# Parsing JSON in Jersey

Tags: arrays, json, jersey

I have a JSON string with multiple key-value pairs and few single objects as under.

I am using Jersey to write a resource class that will read this JSON and convert it to a Java object but I am unable to do so.

Can anyone help me to write the corresponsing Java object and how to parse the JSON to populate this Java object?

```json
{
  "Name": "TestName",
  "MyMap": [
    {
      "key": "Color",
      "value": "red"
    },
    {
      "key": "distance",
      "value": "long"
    },
    {
      "key": "Size",
      "value": "large"
    }
  ]
}
```

My resource class:

```java
@POST
@Path("/somePath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response generateDetails(MyObject myObject) {
    myObject.getName();
    System.out.println("Name " + myObject.getName());
}
```

Comment: thanks guys..I used mapper.readTree and it worked...hurray!!!!

Comment: Sorry guys but my requirement now got changed to below json (basically an array of the list entries) . Please help-{
  "Name": "TestName",
  "MyMap": [
   
   [{
      "key": "Color",
      "value": "red"
    },
    {
      "key": "distance",
      "value": "long"
    },
    {
      "key": "Size",
      "value": "large"
    }],
     [{
      "key": "Color",
      "value": "red"
    },
    {
      "key": "distance",
      "value": "long"
    },
    {
      "key": "Size",
      "value": "large"
    }]
  ]
}

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

### Designing your POJO to work with Jackson

If you are open to use Jackson as a JSON parser, you can have the following:

```java
public class RequestContent {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("MyMap")
    private List<KeyValuePair> map;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

```java
public class KeyValuePair {

    private String key;

    private String value;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

### Parsing the JSON with Jackson

With Jersey and Jackson, you won't need to parse your JSON string with `ObjectMapper`, as shown below:

```java
String json = "{\"Name\":\"TestName\",\"MyMap\":[{\"key\":\"Color\",\"value\":\"red\"},{\"key\":\"distance\",\"value\":\"long\"},{\"key\":\"Size\",\"value\":\"large\"}]}";";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
RequestContent requestContent = mapper.readValue(json, RequestContent.class);
```

Just ensure your resource method look as following and let Jackson's [`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) do the job for you:

```java
@POST 
@Path("/somePath") 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response generateDetails(RequestContent requestContent) {
    ...
}
```

JSON parsing will the automatically handled by the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.java) class, which implements [`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html).

### Jackson dependencies

To use Jackson 2.x as your JSON provider you need to add [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To use Jackson 1.x it'll look like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson1</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all needed dependencies (see [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) or [`jersey-media-json-jackson1`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson1/dependencies.html)) on the classpath.

In order to use Jackson as your JSON provider you need to register [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) (or [`Jackson1Feature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson1/Jackson1Feature.html) for Jackson 1.x) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class.

For more details, check the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html) about support for common media type representations.

### Update based in your requirement change

Change the `RequestContent` class to be like:

```java
public class RequestContent {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("MyMap")
    private List<List<KeyValuePair>> map;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

Then parse the JSON with one of the approaches shown above.

Answer (score -2):

```
1. Create a Pojo class having same keys like your json string contains:
     eg: name , arraylist for your array

 2. Read the above json string and then convert to your pojo.
```

eg:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'gokul'}";
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

Comment: Why would you parse that JSON with `ObjectMapper` in Jersey?

Comment: How does your approach integrates with Jersey?

Comment: I understand that @xmlrootelement also helpful while key match with your json data, weather it coming from ajax call or by any client call. what is you are getting your json string in your class not by any injection . You will have to use object mapper. Its not necessary that every time @ JsonProperty will work.